# Collision code isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I can't understand collision. I know the idea behind it but it is so hard to picture, and I try to write it down but it doesn't work. This is the farthest I've gotten, and while it works, it isn't 100% flawless.
It is a square that moves around. Picture mario, but a square. I am trying to see if theres a block to the left, right, below, or above.

```
function collide(){
var left = avatarX;
var top = avatarY;
var right = avatarX + 50;
var bottom = avatarY + 50;
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length;i+=4){
        var bleft = board[i];
        var btop = board[i+1];
        var bright = board[i + 2] + board[i];
        var bbottom = board[i + 3] + board[i+1];
        if(btop <= bottom && bleft <= left && bright >= right){
            avatarY = board[i + 1] - 50;
        return true;    
        }
    }

return false;   
}
```

Comment: Please add details to your question. Give it context. Right now it's extremely unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is out of context and it's hard to know exactly what you are trying to do. If you are using a grid, I would say that you should check the spaces adjacent to the object you are detecting collisions for. If you post more code, perhaps I can help more.

```
var size = 5;//whatever you want 
var x = new Array(size); 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 x[i] = new Array(size); 
}
```

Comment: What is your board array storing exactly? Positions? Objects? Boolean values?

Comment: board 0/4/8 etc is storing the x
board 1/5/9 is storing the y
board 2/6/10 is storing the width
board 3/7/11 is storing the height.
I will have each level have a big array that's set off stage
Sorry for that confusion

Comment: This is still confusing, but I think the best plan for you would be to make a 2d array and simply check the (x - 1, y), (x, y+1), (x + 1, y), (x, y-1) for objects occupying those array slots. I mean, it's very difficult to understand even what datatype you are storing. 

I would start over, and do something like

    `var size = 5;//whatever you want
    var x = new Array(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     x[i] = new Array(size);
    }`

Comment: I would then make this either store objects or booleans, if it's a simple thing you could honestly just put true in the item that is occupied (you only care about collisions, not necessarily what happens based on what it is colliding with). Just check the adjacent cells for true.